# Automating migration from fuerte to indigo

Tags: catkin, ros-fuerte, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to automate(or semi-automate) this process http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild
I'm surprised as there are no scripts available for this. Has someone tried it before?
I'm on the lookout for where was someone(or I might get) stuck while trying to achieve this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211203/automating-migration-from-fuerte-to-indigo/) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several tools for automating this procedure. On the page you originally linked they discuss the ["catkinize" scripts](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild#Migration_Help_-_.22Catkinize.22_Scripts).
Generally after using them, you still need to do a bit of manual editing, but they are a decent place to begin.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2015-06-12**:
Thanks! I skimmed through the page and missed that section, heh.